# Casting [CustomStruct] as [Any]

Tags: swift, casting

I am trying to cast an array with a custom `Struct` to `[Any]`.

```
struct CustomStruct {}
var cs_array = [CustomStruct]() 
var arr: [Any] = cs_array as [Any]
```

I am getting an error: `CustomStruct is not equal to Any`
I can't figure out why this is. If I make `CustomStruct` a class it works.

Comment: This is strange indeed. Apple states „Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.“ but it does not work for a struct. You can mix Int and Double and class instances in an [Any] array, but no structs. I'd say this is a compiler bug.

Comment: I'm guessing compiler bug as well.

Comment: You could file it with radar. But I've read somewhere about 1300 known issues. I have filed a couple of bugs on my own but not a single one has even been touched by Apple. I'm quite fed up with Swift. It "could" be a nice language :-(

Comment: I am going to file it as a bug. We will see if anything comes out of it.

Comment: Let us know if there is any outcome.